# How can I include a large block of regex with LaTeX?

Tags: regex, latex, formatting

Is it possible to include a large block of a regex (like this one: http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) without escaping all colliding characters first?

I think of something like

```
\begin{following_section_will_not_be_parsed_by_latex}
(a+?b)
\end{...}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can include `\usepackage{listings}` and then use

```
\begin{lstlisting} [code|regex|whatever] \end{lstlisting}
```

Comment: verbatim is a little more lightweight than listings. But yes, both rely on turning LaTeX off for whatever happens inside the environment and turning it back on again afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

Look at [fancyvrb](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyvrb/) package.  From the README:

> The `fancyvrb' package provides very
>   sophisticated facilities for reading
>   and writing verbatim TeX code. Users
>   can perform common tasks like changing
>   font family and size, numbering lines,
>   framing code examples, colouring text
>   and conditionally processing text.

So you can do something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}
\begin{Verbatim}[fontsize=\small,frame=single,label=RFC822 regexp]
...
\end{Verbatim}
```

In order to not clutter your Latex file with the huge regex, you can [include a file verbatim](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=verbfile) as well.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `verbatim` block. But it won't look very nice :(